# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The following code used to work a week ago, but now I'm getting an error:

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Please help.

```
  public analyticsLandingPage verifyReportingProfile() throws InterruptedException{
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//* [@id='reporting_profile_id']")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("Arria");
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    //reporting_profile.findElement(By.xpath(//[@id='s2id_reporting_profile_id']/a")).isDisplayed();
    //reporting_profile.sendKeys("Arria");
    //reporting_profile.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    reporting_profile.isDisplayed();
```

Page HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"     for="reporting_profile_id">Reporting profile</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="s2id_reporting_profile_id" class="select2-container select2-allowclear reporting_profile" style="width: 50%;">
    <a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span id="select2-chosen-7" class="select2-chosen">Agency B - No Adwords Cost or Conversions</span>
    <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
   </a>
   <label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen7">Reporting profile</label>
   <input id="s2id_autogen7" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-7">
    </div>
     <input id="reporting_profile_id" class="reporting_profile" 
      type="hidden" name="reporting_profile_id" tabindex="-1 
      title="Reporting    profile" style="display: none;" value="12">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: there is no data like :- Arria in your HTML which you are trying to search using your code

Comment: There is no select element with id "reporting_profile_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Select class in Selenium.Support.UTI supports only native select element which is

```
<select>
  <option>Item 1</option1>
  <option>Item 2</option1>
  ...
```

But your application is using Select2 which is not select element. In this case, you have to click at `<a class="select2-choice"` then you have to find the option elements (which might be list of `li` or `a`). See example code below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_reporting_profile_id > a.select2-choice")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text()='Arria')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Buaban. What if there is no <option> element.

Comment: <div id="s2id_reporting_profile_id" class="select2-container select2-allowclear reporting_profile" style="width: 50%;">
<a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span id="select2-chosen-8" class="select2-chosen">AdOps Reporting Profile</span>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"/>
<span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it might be `<li>` or `<a>`. Could you show me full HTML (screenshot or a file)?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you try the example code? If it doesn't work,  please try to change the XPath expression to `By.xpath("//li[contains(text()='Arria')]")` or `By.xpath("//span[contains(text()='Arria')]")` or `By.xpath("//a[contains(text()='Arria')]")`